# Add a callback to send click event

Tags: c#, callback, outlook-addin

I would like that when a user sends his mail, a copy of it is made, and sent to another person, to be archived. The user uses a keyword to specify whether the mail should be archived. (I need to add some data in the second mail, that should not appear in the 1st)

So I developed in C# an addin, where I intercept the click "sent" event to copy the mail and send it. Only, it is impossible to send a second email in this event. So I thought about adding a callback to my event, so that once the first email is sent, the second one is sent, but I can't implement a callback to my code (I don't know how to do it on the event, or even if it's possible)

```
    Outlook.MailItem mailCopy; //Copy of my first mail
    bool sndCopy = false;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend); //event click send
    }
    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Outlook.Application oApp;
        Outlook._NameSpace oNS;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder oFolder;
        oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        oNS = (Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        Outlook.MailItem mail1 = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;


        this.mailCopy = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

        foreach(Outlook.Recipient rcp in mail.Recipients){
           if(rcp.Address == "Robots"){
               this.sndCopy = true;
               break;
            }
        }

    }
```

two emails must be sent, the first one that can be sent to anyone, a second one that must be sent to a robot for archiving at an email address (robot@google.fr for example) with other additional data that cannot appear in the 1st

Edit Solution : 
I modified my code by adding an event on the creation of a file, when I save my message in a directory

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;


        this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend); //event click send

        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {


        Outlook.Application oApp;
        Outlook._NameSpace oNS;
        oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        oNS = (Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;

        mail.SaveAs(path + "\\files.msg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

    }

    private void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem msg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(path + "\\files.msg", Type.Missing);
        msg.Send();
        File.Delete(path + "\\files.msg");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer (use the Timer class from the Forms namespace as it fires on the primary thread) and enable it in the `Application.ItemSend` event. Create the new message, save it, store its entry id in a list. When the timer fires, disable the timer, open the messages (`Namespace.GetItemfromID`) using the entry ids saved in your list, send them, clear the list.

Comment: Can't i use somethings like async, await or AsyncCallback ?

Comment: No. Outlook Object Model cannot be used on a secondary thread.

Comment: I found another solution, which I just posted! Thank you for the help and information!

Comment: This is the equivalent of a timer - you get an asynchronous callback on the same thread.